# Error while using multipicklist field by reference on formula

Tags: formula-field, multi-select

I have a custom account multi-select field that I need to use on a custom contact checkbox formula field. When I used like this:

> ISBLANK( Account.Custom_Multiselect__c )

I get this error on the record detail: **#Error!**

Instead, if I use a multi-select on the contact itself, the same formula works:

> ISBLANK(Custom_Multiselect__c )

I know this formula by itself doesn't make sense, but it is just part of the final formula, obviously more complex. That final formula doesn't work if this section gives that error

Any idea? Is there some kind of limitation on whe type of fields that can be used by reference on formulas?

I must add that I'm using Personal Accounts, I don't know if that changes something at all

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal but you could create a *boolean* **formula field** on the original object and then create a **formula field** on the target object with an IF() that references the boolean value via a lookup.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Actually I have realized I can't use any of the Account fields. I guees taht this is because I am using Person Accounts? Can't I use Account.AnyField on formulas??